# how to assign log as a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, logs, variable

I want to assign log output to "line", I tried the following 
`line=tail -1000 /var/log/syslog`

but it doesn't work.

myscript is like below

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

line=`tail -1000 /var/log/syslog`
d1=$(date --date="-10 min" "+%b %_d %H:%M")
d2=$(date "+%b %_d %H:%M")
while read line; do
    [[ $line > $d1 && $line < $d2 || $line =~ $d2 ]] && echo $line
done
```

Comment: You are doing wrong: you are thinking like a procedural programmer for shell scripting. Use pipes and xargs (to execute at every line your command).

Comment: `xargs` and uncontrolled output from a log sounds like a bad idea. — It seems that what you are actually trying to do is to get the log from the last 10 minutes, right? This should be easily done with `journalctl`. — Also you needs quotes around your variables, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls . If you still want to do this as a shell script, go ahead. Otherwise just use Python.

Answer (score 2):

Try this change

```
fd=""
tmplog="/tmp/temp_${$$}_${RANDOM}"
tail -1000 /var/log/syslog > "$tmplog"

exec {fd}<"$tmplog"

while IFS='' read -r -u $fd line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    #your commands here
done

exec {fd}>&-
rm "$tmplog"
```

How it works:
Assign `fd` as a variable.
Create a temp file using the script PID and the built in "RANDOM" number (you could also use the mktemp command in place of this).
Open the file descriptor `fd` for reading of the temp file.
Use while loop with `IFS` set to nothing and run read command with `-u` option to read from `fd`.
Put your commands inside the loop using the same `line` variable.
Close the file descriptor.
Remove the temp file.

Comment: @Prabash - did this solution work for you? If so please mark it as correct. If not what problem did you encounter?

Comment: Actually ,I want to get count of number of records in last 1 hour log.
below logic and code one work fines for me. Thnks for ur support ,
nowdate=$(date +'%H:%M:')
pastdate=$(date +'%H:%M:' -d "1 hour ago")

echo $nowdate
echo $pastdate

sed -rne "/$pastdate/,/$nowdate/p" /data/recvdmsg.log | wc -l

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment works fine -- although `$( ... )` is more robust and better style than backticks. But `read line` doesn't read *from* line, it reads from stdin (the terminal, since you didn't redirect it) *into* line, destroying the previous contents. Try one of:

```
data=$(tail -1000 /file) 
while read line; do echo "$line"; done <<<"$data"
# bash ksh zsh but maybe not older shells
# or 
while read line; do echo "$line"; done < <(tail -1000 file)
# ditto 

data=$(tail -1000 /file) 
echo "$data" | while read line; do echo "$line"; done 
# or
tail -1000 file | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
# most shells, but any var set (or other shell change made) within the loop 
# will disappear on _some_ shells because pipelines are run in subshells
```

with appropriate commands added in the loop.

In general to keep data unmangled by `read` you need `-r` as shown by EnterUserNameHere, but syslog entries are pretty structured and shouldn't need it for any case I can think of. OTOH adding it won't hurt and is good practice.

Note comparing datestrings won't work early on the first day of some months; for example if now-10min is "Nov 31 23:55" and now is "Dec 01 00:05" then all of the datestrings that are actually between those two times will *fail* the test `$line > $d1 && $line < $d2`